# YouTube API volume toggle

Tags: api, youtube

Would like to know if it's possible (and how) using the YouTube iframe API to have an html button or link, external to the player, to toggle the sound on and off.

Thanks,
Mauro

Comment: see [this](http://www.tikku.com/jquery-youtube-tubeplayer-plugin#tubeplayer_tutorial_1)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

see [jQuery Youtube Plugin](http://www.tikku.com/jquery-youtube-tubeplayer-plugin#tubeplayer_tutorial_1) for complete specs and download.
     
It will be possible to declare a player like this:

```
 jQuery("#youtube-player-container").tubeplayer({
        width: 600, // the width of the player
        height: 450, // the height of the player
        allowFullScreen: "true", // true by default, allow user to go full screen
        initialVideo: "DkoeNLuMbcI", // the video that is loaded into the player
        preferredQuality: "default",// preferred quality: default, small, medium, large, hd720
        onPlay: function(id){}, // after the play method is called
        onPause: function(){}, // after the pause method is called
        onStop: function(){}, // after the player is stopped
        onSeek: function(time){}, // after the video has been seeked to a defined point
        onMute: function(){}, // after the player is muted
        onUnMute: function(){} // after the player is unmuted
    });
Then just add a link with the desired function:
<a href="#" onClick='jQuery("#youtube-player-container").tubeplayer("mute")'>   
Mute player
```

Comment: There is no need to use any external plugins since the youtube api is already providing you with `player.mute()` and `player.unMute()` to toggle sound and `player.isMuted()` to check the state of sound channel. This solution is overcoding, when you could use a simple javascript click event...